# Get device name from usb

Tags: c++, linux

[lsusb command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgVAJ.png)

i want to get device name like on lsusb. I found this code and i tried its all descriptor parameters.Is there any way to get device name like on picture like Log. Opt. Gam. Mouse

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>
main(){
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();
    for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next){
            printf("Trying device %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
            printf("\tID_VENDOR = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
            printf("\tID_PRODUCT = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idProduct);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the poiter for you is look into libusb library.

starting with libusb_get_device_list which Returns a list of USB devices currently attached to the system.
https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__dev.html

you can take it from there.

if you want other way reading /sys/bus/usb/devices directory and read valid devices.
except root hub or other hubs.

EDIT1:

updated link

here is usage

```c
libusb_device **list;
ssize_t cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &list);
ssize_t i = 0;
if (cnt < 0)
    handle_error(); //handle error and return
 
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    libusb_device *device = list[i];
    // do your work
}
 
libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
```

Comment: i tried "libusb_get_device_list" but it is not giving the result i want.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @RaleighL updated link. and added sample code to try out .

Comment: Neither the link or the code snippet explains how to get the *name* of each enumerated device.

Comment: Indeed, how do you get the name of the usb device?

Comment: https://github.com/tenderlove/libusb/blob/7634714aa696175b08016b6f2185a75a2f55a113/libusb/descriptor.c#L427-L436
using 
```
       int API_EXPORTED libusb_get_device_descriptor(libusb_device *dev,
 struct libusb_device_descriptor *desc)
```

https://github.com/tenderlove/libusb/blob/7634714aa696175b08016b6f2185a75a2f55a113/libusb/libusb.h#L394-L445

this is defination of struct libusb_device_descriptor .

```
           printf("%04x:%04x \n", desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct);
```

this will print vendor and productID. you can use other info from desc.

Comment: @Devidas those are ids. the question was clearly about the name.